# paper-drawer-panel in Polymer Dart 1.0 rc. 5 do not render properly..... where am I wrong, please?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm new to programming in Dart Polymer, but I don't know how to adjust my code for render properly `paper-drawer-panel` with Dart Polymer 1.0.0-rc.5

The output of my execution is two lines one above the other..... not the drawer panel....!

Like this:

Main panel...

Drawer panel...

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ispections - 2015</title>
    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_header_panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_drawer_panel.html">
  </head>

  <body class="fullbleed unresolved">

    <paper-drawer-panel class="standard-paper-drawer-panel">
      <div drawer> Drawer panel... </div>
      <div main> Main panel... </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>

    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.dart

```
import 'package:polymer/init.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_header_panel.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_drawer_panel.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_toolbar.dart';

main() async {
  await initPolymer();
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: inspections2015
description: Programma inspections2015
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  polymer: "^1.0.0-rc.5"
  web_components: "^0.12.0-rc.3"
  browser: "^0.10.0-rc.2"
  reflectable: "^0.3.3"
  polymer_elements: "^1.0.0-rc.3"
transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.dart
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test{.*,}.dart
- $dart2js:
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
dev_dependencies:
  test: ^0.12.3
environment:
  sdk: ">=1.8.0 <2.0.0"
```

stile.css

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Does it look like the screenshot in https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/issues/105? See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/issues/93

Comment: You are right..... I have the same screwed up layout and there is no way to see the drawer panel. But for me this happen in every browser I use.

Comment: The basic example seems to work fine in Dart http://bwu-dart.github.io/polymer_elements_demos/web/index.html. I haven't tried anything else myself yet. (source https://github.com/bwu-dart/polymer_elements_demos/tree/master/web/paper_drawer_panel)